# How to use the Perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

I want to debug a Perl program using

```
perl -d example.pl
```

I have read `perldebug`, but it is too abstract for me, so I think I need an example to practise it step by step.

Comment: This is a video I prepared: http://perlmaven.com/using-the-built-in-debugger-of-perl  This is the second part of a series: http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2014/04/learning-the-perl-debugger-lesson-2/ not by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is like *"please can you give me an example how to drive a car"*.

I have explained the basic commands that you will use most often. Beyond this you must read the debugger's inline help and reread the [**perldebug**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) documentation

- The debugger starts by displaying the *next* line to be executed: usually the first line in your program
- Debugger commands are mostly single letters, possibly with parameters. The command will be actioned as soon as you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- You should concentrate on commands `s` and `n` to step through the program. If the next statement is a subroutine (or method) call then `s` will step *into* the subroutine while `n` will step *over* the call. Otherwise `s` and `n` behave identically

  Be careful using `s` when a single line of code contains multiple subroutine calls. You may not be stepping into the subroutine that you expect.

  You can't step *into* a built-in function, or a subroutine not written in Perl.

  Once you have executed a statement there is no going back. You must restart the program to try something different.
- You can execute a line of Perl code just by typing it in and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. the code will be executed in the context of the current statement

  You can examine or *modify* any variable this way.
- The `p` command is *identical* to `print`. The output from `p $var` or `p @arr` will be the same as if you had typed `p $var` or `p @arr`
- You can use `x` to dump an expression in *list* context. The output consists of numbered lines showing each element of the list
- The commands dot `.`, hyphen `-` and `v` are useful for looking at the source code. `.` and `-` will display the current and previous source line respectively. `v` will display a window around the current source line
- To rapidly return to a specific line of code you can set a *breakpoint* and continue execution until that line using the `c` command. For example `c 13`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute all code until line 13 and then stop

  Breakpoints defined using `c` are *temporary*, so if you want to continue to the same line again (in a loop) then you have to enter `c 13`<kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

  `c` without any parameters will run the rest of the program until it exits or until a permanent breakpoint, defined using `b`, is reached.
- You can specify breakpoints with more complex conditions using the `b` command. They can be deleted only with the corresponding `B` command, or `B *` which will clear all breakpoints
- `h` shows a list of the commands available, and `h *command*`, like `h c`, will show you detailed help on a single command
- Finally, `q` will end the debug session and terminate the program

The debugger will do a lot more than this, but these are the basic commands that you need to know. You should experiment with them and look at the contents of the help text to get more proficient with the Perl debugger.

Comment: can you give me a perl example code to debug or Learning Video to watch?

Comment: I have become accustomed to the visual studio GUI debuging,but I want to experience the command line debuging

Comment: Thanks! I really read your reply,But I want to practise debug with code step by step(this is the most important). Youtube is blocked by the Great FireWall of China.

Comment: Thanks,I cannot reach that site.It is blocked too!My English is too poor.Maybe I should ask some Chinese for help.

Comment: Things are always difficult at the start.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Finally,I use the most stupid but the most efficient debug method--add some code like this "print some variable" in my code,and I add some breakpoint at those lines.

Comment: @cn8341: You can do that by typing `p $some_variable` into the debugger when it pauses at the breakpoint

Comment: I know p $some_variable,but I hate to type p $some_variable every time if there are too many variables ,and I want to know the value of variable auto (not type every time ) .Is there any method to display the values of some variables autoly every time before <DBnumber> except print variable in code

Comment: Yes, you can put a Perl string to be evaluated at a breakpoint, so `b 13 print "$v1\n"; print "$v2\n"` will display `$v1` and `$v2` when it hits line 13

Comment: very Good! but why I do not find such usage in perldoc?http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html

Comment: @cn8341: It's the `[condition]` in that document. `print` always returns 1 (if it's successful) so the breakpoint always pauses after executing it. If you used something like `print "$v1\n"; 0` then it would print the value but continue without pausing

Comment: @cn8341: Note that the `y` command will display all lexical variables currently in scope (those declared with `my`) which may be what you want